# Get height of div containing image with js offsetHeight

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to get the height of a div containing a headline and an image. All I get back is the height of the heading. If I add a specific height to the container div I get the correct height (in this case 300px), but I need the different heights. Thx for any help!

My js code:

```
var tile1 = document.getElementById('t1').offsetHeight;
```

My HTML:

```
<div class="t" id="t1" style="height:300px !important;">
   <article>
      <header class="beitrag">
         <div class="beitrag-meta">Date: 2016-11-02 19:59:45</div>
      </header>
      <div class="beitrag-inhalt"><img src="219594520163877.jpg" ></div>
  </article>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you run it after the page has been loaded.

Stack snippet

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var tile1 = document.getElementById('t1').offsetHeight;
  console.log(tile1);
})
```

```html
<div class="t" id="t1">
   <article>
      <header class="beitrag">
         <div class="beitrag-meta">Date: 2016-11-02 19:59:45</div>
      </header>
      <div class="beitrag-inhalt"><img src="http://placehold.it/100/"></div>
  </article>
</div>
```

Or with a script tag at the bottom of the `body`

Stack snippet

```html
<div class="t" id="t1">
   <article>
      <header class="beitrag">
         <div class="beitrag-meta">Date: 2016-11-02 19:59:45</div>
      </header>
      <div class="beitrag-inhalt"><img src="http://placehold.it/100/"></div>
  </article>
</div>

<script>
  var tile1 = document.getElementById('t1').offsetHeight;
  console.log(tile1);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery `load` function

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("img").load(function() {
     var tile1 = document.getElementById('t1').clientHeight;
     alert("height: "+tile1);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="t" id="t1">
   <article>
      <header class="beitrag">
         <div class="beitrag-meta">Date: 2016-11-02 19:59:45</div>
      </header>
      <div class="beitrag-inhalt"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x350" ></div>
  </article>
</div>
```